# LWC conditional display on load of component not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, conditional, if, html-template-directives

Based on the field values of the Account, I want to display/hide parts of the component when it loads for the first time. I have tried so many things unsuccessfully and am hoping someone can help me find a way to do this.

The component sits on the standard Account page, and gets the Account's values from the recordId passed. I added a custom formula field on Account called isOrg__c which is a checkbox (true/false). Regardless of what the value in Org__c is, it sees it as false/undefined.

```
 <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-m-around_medium">
  <lightning-record-view-form
    record-id={recordId}
    object-api-name="Account">
    <p>Current Verification Status</p>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-box">
      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Name"></lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="isOrg__c"></lightning-output-field>
        <template if:false={isOrg__c}>
          <lightning-output-field field-name="PersonEmail"></lightning-output-field>
        </template>
        <template if:true={isOrg__c}>
          This is an ORG!!!!
        </template>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Membership_Status__c"></lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Identity_Status__c"></lightning-output-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </lightning-record-view-form>
</div>
```

I added the field to the display to make sure what the value is - it is set to true (checked), so why is it displaying the Email field, and not the 'This is an ORG' text?

[image]
[image]

The JS code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import { getRecord, createRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from "lightning/pageReferenceUtils";

import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Account";
import ISORGFIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.isOrg__c";

const FIELDS = [
  "Account.Id",
  "Account.FirstName",
  "Account.LastName",
  "Account.PersonEmail",
  "Account.isOrg__c",
  "Account.isPersonAccount"
];
const DELAY = 300;

export default class VerifyAccount extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  @track error;
  @track record;
  @track isPerson;
  @track isOrg;

  //Account variables
  @track fname;
  @track lname;
  @track aemail;
  @track aid;

  @api recordId;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: FIELDS })
  wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.record = data;
      this.aid = this.record.fields.Id.value;
      this.fname = this.record.fields.FirstName.value;
      this.lname = this.record.fields.LastName.value;
      this.aemail = this.record.fields.PersonEmail.value;
      this.isPerson = this.record.fields.isPersonAccount.value;
      this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.record = undefined;
    }
  }

  handleLoad(event) {
    this.isOrg = event.detail.data.isOrg__c;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share with us the js code that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

`{isOrg__c}` is trying to refer to a variable in your controller `isOrg__c`. Presumably, you haven't defined it. Try:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ISORGFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.isOrg__c';

export default class XYZ extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId; 
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [ISORGFIELD] }) record;
  get isOrg() {
    return getFieldValue(this.record.data, ISORGFIELD);
  }
  get isLoaded() {
    return !!this.record.data;
  }
}
```

---

```
   <template if:true={isLoaded}
    <template if:false={isOrg}>
      <lightning-output-field field-name="PersonEmail"></lightning-output-field>
    </template>
    <template if:true={isOrg}>
      This is an ORG!!!!
    </template>
  </template>
```

---

Alternatively, the following change should work:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ISORGFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.isOrg__c';


export default class XYZ extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  isOrg = false;
  handleLoad(event) {
    this.isOrg = getFieldValue(event.detail.records[this.recordId], ISORGFIELD);
  }
}
```

---

```
<lightning-record-edit-form onload={handleLoad} ...
```

Comment: I'll try that. Why does it not use the field straight from the Account? It obviously has the value as it displays it. Can't one use the field value like this in a condition?

Comment: @Irene No, because the lightning-record-view-form has the data, but anything in a `{...}` refers to data in your own component. A bit of a round-about way, but that's how it works. Note that getRecord should immediately return a cached copy of the record anyways, so it shouldn't matter. The rest of the stuff demonstrated here is just how you'd load a field and make conditions on it, much different than you would in Aura.

Comment: @Irene Actually, checking the docs, you could probably read the data from the lightning-record-view-form `load` event, which would save you a bit of boilerplate... Let me edit.

Comment: I'm getting ' [Cannot read property 'isOrg__c' of undefined]' if I try with the handleLoad(event)?

Comment: @Irene Hmm, I'll test it out. Give me a few.

Comment: @sfdcfox.. haha... true!! didnt notice, I got it from [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record) and quickly edited here... Removed my ans

Comment: I added my js code in now too.

Comment: @Irene Had to debug the code, it expects us to use a kind of weird format. In the interim, I'll review your code.

Comment: Thanks - I'm really tearing my hair out and need help...

Comment: @Irene your if:true/if:else parts are still using `isOrg__c`? It should be `isOrg` (or change my code to match). Also, I recommend the use of field tokens and getFieldValue/getFieldDisplayValue to get the fields from the record. Also, since you're already using a wire service, why not just read isOrg__c from there? `this.isOrg = getFieldValue(this.record, ISORGFIELD);`

Comment: @salesforce-sas No worries, by the way, it happens to all of us. Also, congrats on 15k in such a short period of time. Your contributions are definitely appreciated.

Comment: @sfdcfox I haven't updated the html in my question here no, but have in my org - it is just using {isOrg} in there now. I've now changed the call as in your last comment in the handleLoad event, but that throws an error ' [getFieldValue is not defined]', so I presume you mean add this to the 'if (data) {....' section?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107938/discussion-between-sfdcfox-and-irene).